What are downsides of using composite type and array of composite type columns in TimescaleDB hypertable
I'm considering to use a composite type and array of composite type columns in TimescaleDB hypertable. I'm curious whether using such columns has any downsides like less effective compression comparing to using a standard data type and arrays of standard data types. Somehow related question is how well TimescaleDB supports columns that store arrays of standard types.

All non-predefined types will end up in the dictionary category, so it will use a map to compress the data. This blog post gives  a great explaining on the types: https://www.timescale.com/blog/time-series-compression-algorithms-explained/

@jonatasdp thank you for the link, unfortunately they aren't very explicit about how dictionary compression would be used for complex types where each cell contains multiple values
